# How to determine the existence of this function

Tags: real-analysis

Does exist $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ for $(x_0,x_0)$ such that $$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\right)_{(x_0,y_0)}>0$$ for every direction $v$?

Comment: Hint: If you are walking upward in a road, when you walk in the opposite direction, you are going downward.

Comment: You should use \partial instead of \delta for partial derivatives.

Comment: By the chain rule, the derivative on $-v$ is minus the derivative on $v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If $v = \langle a,b \rangle$ is a unit vector and $w = \langle -a,-b \rangle$ then
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(x_0,y_0) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + ah,y_0+bh)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac{f(x_0 + ah,y_0+bh)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0^-}\frac{f(x_0 - ah,y_0-bh)}{-h} \\
&= -  \lim_{h \to 0^-}\frac{f(x_0 - ah,y_0-bh)}{h} \\
&= - \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x_0 - ah,y_0-bh)}{h} \\
&= - \frac{\partial f}{\partial w}(x_0,y_0)
\end{align*}
because both directional derivatives are assumed to exist. More specifically if $f$ is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$ then
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}(x_0,y_0) = \nabla f(x_0,y_0) \cdot w =  - \nabla f(x_0,y_0) \cdot v = - \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(x_0,y_0).$$

In any event, $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}(x_0,y_0)$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial w}(x_0,y_0)$ can't both be positive.